# How to get return data from function in another js file on javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can i retrieve a return data in another file js?

this is my user.js looks like

```
export default function getUser() {
    const data = localStorage.getItem("user-account")
    //console.log(data.user.ID)
    const user = {
        ID: data.user.ID,
        Name: data.user.Name, 
    }
  return user;
}
```

and i want to import them and get the return user in another file js,
because i want to use this file as global function
any solution?

Comment: import getUser from that file and run it?

Comment: and how to console log the return after i import and run it?

Comment: using `console.log` is the usual way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try importing it into another file and logging the result.

```
import getUser from './user'

console.log(getUser())
```

Take note that you need a script type of 'module' for this to work